# Postgres COPY TO / FROM A FILE as non superuser

Tags: file, postgresql, copy, root

im trying to create a function that any user can call in order to copy data from/to a file... my idea is to set a function that acts as a superuser or one that is executed as "postgres" but I dont know were to start to begin with.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for "SECURITY DEFINER". See docs for details http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: That's awesome, thanks.

Do you know if its possible to pass table, fields and file path as extensions to a function? lets say:

COPY $table ($fields) FROM $path with csv;

BTW I'm using postres 8.4 and testing as I write this :P

Comment: You'll want to use EXECUTE and also do some validation on your parameters.

Comment: Thanks I think I can find my way from here ;)