# Postgres SQL - error: must be superuser to copy to or from a file

Tags: postgresql, csv, privileges, postgresql-copy

I have copied function(from one of the webportal and modified accordingly) to copy data from csv file to table.

```
create or replace function public.load_csv_file
(
target_table text,
csv_path text,
col_count integer
)

returns void as $$

declare

iter integer; -- dummy integer to iterate columns with
col text; -- variable to keep the column name at each iteration
col_first text; -- first column name, e.g., top left corner on a csv file or     spreadsheet

begin
set schema 'public';

create table insert_from_csv ();

-- add just enough number of columns
for iter in 1..col_count
loop
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv add column col_%s text;', iter);
end loop;

-- copy the data from csv file
execute format('copy insert_from_csv from %L with delimiter '','' quote ''"'' csv ', csv_path);

iter := 1;
col_first := (select col_1 from insert_from_csv limit 1);

-- update the column names based on the first row which has the column names
for col in execute format('select unnest(string_to_array(trim(temp_table::text, ''()''), '','')) from temp_table where col_1 = %L', col_first)
loop
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename column col_%s to %s', iter, col);
    iter := iter + 1;
end loop;

-- delete the columns row
execute format('delete from insert_from_csv where %s = %L', col_first, col_first);

-- change the temp table name to the name given as parameter, if not blank
if length(target_table) > 0 then
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename to %I', target_table);
end if;

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

And 
passing parameters as

select load_csv_file('Customer','C:\Insert_postgres.csv' ,4)

but getting error message

ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
  Hint: Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.

The idea is, i will create a automated test, and if i want to test on different instance then test should automatically create function and copy data from csv file.
Is there any work around to copy data without superuser?

Comment: The executing user will need permissions on the file system. I believe this defaults to the /home directory. Can you grant the executing user read/write on the directories the copy files exist ?

Comment: Yes, the user i am using has those rights.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268420/postgres-copy-to-from-a-file-as-non-superuser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres COPY TO / FROM A FILE as non superuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268420/postgres-copy-to-from-a-file-as-non-superuser)

Answer (score 2):

Looks Insert_postgres.csv is in C drive which usually does not have Read/Write permission. Move the file to your directory where Read/Write given atleast to some groups or everyone. 
Hope it will resolve the issue

Comment: I tried moving file to c:\Test\Insert_postgres.csv,but still getting same error. 
Note: The postgres user which i am using is not superuser.

Comment: To make a user a SuperUser: ALTER USER username WITH SUPERUSER;
    To make a user no longer a SuperUser: ALTER USER username WITH NOSUPERUSER;
    To just allow the user to create a database: ALTER USER username CREATEDB;

You can also use CREATEROLE and CREATEUSER to allow a user privileges without making them a superuser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757431/postgres-upgrade-a-user-to-be-a-superuser (for more information)

Comment: Hi Priya, thanks for the answer, but the user i have isn't a superuser so can't alter it's permissions. What i am trying to achive is, I am going to automate this process, so i want to repeat the activity again and again with just click, So i am looking for solution to copy without being superuser.

Comment: After doing extensive research on this subject... you cannot use the COPY statement without being a SuperUser.  End of story.   :-)

Comment: you can use \copy instead of COPY to get the job done. COPY <rest> wont work unless you are a superuser \copy <rest> will work as long as you have select and insert permissions. End of story :--)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in terminal. This allows us to use COPY command, since you can't use COPY command without being a super user.

```
ALTER USER <username> WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Comment: You have to *be* a super user to do this.